# how can I edit the code button in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have installed prettyprint in my Wordpress theme. Now in order to use it, I need to wrap my code in:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
<code> 
     code here
</code>
</pre>
```

Now the code button on Wordpress html editor provides only the `<code></code>` tag. Now is there a way to edit this so that I can add the extra `span`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your functions.php:

```
function my_quicktags() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_quicktags' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/quicktags.js' , array('quicktags') );
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts' , 'my_quicktags');
```

Create a file called `quicktags.js`, place it into a `js` folder, in your theme directory.

Copy all the content of your `/includes/js/quicktags.js` file. You can edit/delete/add anything, specially the last strings, which are the corresponding to editor tags.

Now you can add your span:

```
edButtons[15] = new qt.TagButton('span-1','My Span','<span class="myClass">','</span>','X');
```

That means:

```
edButtons[position] = new qt.TagButton('ID','Display Name (value)','opening tag','ending tag','shortcut key');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is great. I found the other buttons which seem to have the same code as your last line. So now not only than I create a new one (as you showed) but it seems I can edit the originals, which is what I wanted - thanks a lot man

Comment: Yes, you can edit/remove/sort the existing buttons as you wish.